# TypeError: state.buffer is not iterable when using Hardhat

Tags: localhost, hardhat

I followed the instruction as hardhat's https://hardhat.org/getting-started/ .

1. npx hardhat node. And then I can connect to it with metamask.
2. npx hardhat run scripts/sample-script.js --network localhost to deploy the example.

But it returns me as below error:

```
TypeError: state.buffer is not iterable

like below:

$ npx hardhat run scripts/sample-script.js --network localhost


/Users/********/workspace/testHardhat1/node_modules/undici/lib/api/readable.js:211

  for (const chunk of state.buffer) {

                            ^
TypeError: state.buffer is not iterable
    at consumeStart 
(/Users/******/workspace/testHardhat1/node_modules/undici/lib/api/readable.js:211:29)

    at processTicksAndRejections 
(internal/process/task_queues.js:83:17)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your node version, I was using a node version that is non-compatible with hardhat (Version 10.01) and after update to 16.14.0 that issue was fixed.

Comment: Thanks , I just updated the node version,but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with node v16.14.0 .downgrading to node version v14.0.0 worked.